# Explanation of windows.open on IE? Why does this work on chrome and not on IE?

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a html page where an option is selected from dropdown, and button clicks opens a new page.
Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </head>
  <body>
    <p><form name="edit" method="post">
        <div>CHOOSE:</div>
        <div><select name="Edi" id ="Edi" >
            <option selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="edit.php?table=Alpha">Adam</option>
            <option value="edit.php?table=Beta">Brandon</option>
        </select>
        <input onclick="return Edit();" type="submit" value="Edit"/></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Edit()
        {
            if(document.forms['edit'].Edi.value == "Select")
            {
                alert("Please Select Edit Field");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
               window.open(Edi.value);
               return true;
            }
        } 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is edit.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $Table = $_GET['table'];
        echo $Table;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason i have done it like this, because i want to add more options in index.html that will open a different page(not edit.php).

This code runs fine on Google Chrome, but not on IE. My initial guess was some sort of comptability issue(and it still might be).

But then i made this `window.open(Edi.value);` to this `window.open("http://www.yahoo.com");` and it works on both Chrome and IE. Why? What is the reason that edit.php page wont open for IE 10?

Comment: Your doctype tag seems broken on index.html
This could be it, since chrome is known to try a lot harder than other browsers to display a page regardless of errors.

Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I messed it up copying. I edited it

Comment: If only it could have been that simple, haha.

Comment: Referring an element with its id directly from JS is deprecated for a decade ago, and it's not implemented in all modern browsers at all. Use `getElementById` instead. Also, the code would be more cross-browser, if you'd use `selectedIndex` property of `select` element instead of its value. I.e. the value of the selected option is `select[select.selectedIndex].value`, and get `select` with `gEBI()`.

Comment: What comes to your previous question, don't use hacks (the x-ua meta tag is a hack), just remove the ticks from checkboxes in Compatibility View settings, and use the Dev Tools to make sure you're running your browser in edge mode.